# is there a way to take input from case 1 to case 2 in java?

Tags: java, xml, switch-statement

case 1 the user needs to validate the XML file.
case 2 I need to check if the user validated the XML file and if validation = true I need to display the info of the XML file
my problem is **how can I check if the user validated the XML**

even if I validate the XML when I inset 2 it is always false

```
boolean valid = false;

  switch (number)
      {
      case 1 :
          validation();
          
         break;

         
         
      case 2 :
         if (validtrue(valid) == true) 
             System.out.println("true");// checking 
         
         else
            
        System.out.println("please validate the XML file first  ");
         break;

static void validation()
{

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the name of te XML file wiht .xml");
    String xmlFName = sc.nextLine();
    try {
    
    File file = new File(xmlFName); // validate the xml 
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
    NodeList lst = doc.getElementsByTagName("book");
    }catch(Exception e)
    
    
    
    {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
    
    System.out.println("the "+ xmlFName +" file has been validated ");
    boolean valid = true;
    validtrue(valid);
    
    }

static boolean validtrue(boolean valid)
{
    
    if valid == true 
    
    return true;
    
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: The point of your `validtrue` method is unclear.

Comment: That all depends on how you're planning to do it. You could validate and display in one go, you could display the menu again or you could use multiple runs. I assume you want to display the menu again so use a loop here.

Comment: if you remove the break in case 1 it will fall through to case 2. but the way i understand it you shouldn't really use a switch/case for this. you should first run `if (!valid(foo)) return;` for example as a guard clause. and if that is ok run whatever other logic you need

Comment: @Thomas yeh I did " do while" that's not my full code I just posted the important part of my question the problem if the user started with case 2 i need to check if he validated in case 1

Comment: @Arnaud the validtrue method I wrote it down just to try some logic and it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have two menu options: 1 where user validates something and 2 where user does something if validation has been made. And it is required that user should be able to go to option 2 without doing option 1. You could try something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myInput = new Scanner( System.in );
    boolean validated = false;
    int option;
    while(true){
        option = myInput.nextInt();

        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                validated = validation();
                break;
            case 2:
                if (validated){
                    System.out.println("true");// checking
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("please validate the XML file first  ");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

}

private static boolean validation(){
    return true; //or false
}
```